# Xpath fetching node by attributes

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

This should be rather a simple task, but for some reasons a part of my xml file hasn't been read properly...

This is the XML Section in question:

```
<MTX>
...
<MoClass code=".0" modi="XYZ">
.....
</MoClass>
......
</MTX>
```

Now, i want to fetch the Node by following code:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file(filename)

 //this fails due to invalid predicate...
 $xml->xPath('//MoClass[@code=".0" AND @modi="XYZ"]');

 //but when i reverse the sequence of attributes 
 $xml->xPath('//MoClass[@modi="XYZ" AND @code=".0"]');
 //then it works as expected and the node may be processed further...
```

What is the difference?
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath is case-sensitive. Use `and` instead of 'AND'

[**demo**](https://eval.in/904205)

Comment: Glad t help. Good luck!